# Im trying to import an stl file to edit for 3d printing, however, when i import it, the file loads as a single point

Tags: edit-mode, import

[image]I thought it was a problem with the file, but it loads into my slicer and windows 3d viewer just fine. i tryed upscaling the model to see if it was just tiny, but nothing happened is when I realized it spawned it as a dot. other files are importing the same way. anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: please put a link of your file so I can help you with it

Comment: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3734614

Answer (score 0):

scale down to 0.001 and you will see your model. you can apply transforms by hitting `Ctrl`+`A` and selecting scale.

point: if you check dimension values you will see big values. It means blender has imported vertices but they are not in our view.